# Spark - Not able to recognize delta table, but its a delta table

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I am trying to use spark 3.2.0, and delta-Core-1.1.0.jar, and am getting following error

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: `default`.`testData` is not a
> Delta table.

This is how I am saving the dataset:
`tableDataset.write().option("path", clientId + "/" + jobname + "/" + tableName).format("delta").saveAsTable(tableName);`

When I use the spark 3.0, and delta-core-0.8.jar, code works fine.

Kindly let us know what needs to be modified wrt upgraded Spark.

Comment: please post full exception

Comment: Was able to solve the issue, it was due to spark metastore was not getting set. When we removed ".option("path", clientId + "/" + jobname + "/" + tableName)", issue got solved